# How can we integrate Microsoft planner with Power Bi

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi, microsoft-planner

As I checked there is no planner connector available in Power Bi. Is there any way to connect planner with Power Bi directly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific connector for this, but you can leverage on `OData feed` in Power BI to query via Microsoft Graph API.

[image]

1. Open your Power BI, click on Get Data > OData Feed.
2. Paste the following URL (just for testing) `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/planner/tasks`.
3. Make sure you're selecting `Organizational account` to connect and click on Sign In.
4. Proceed to do your magic!

I don't think you would need other operations like to modify or create task except just get the data. I'm not sure if Power BI would be able to do that, but you can also [integrate Power Automate in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-flow-powerbi-report).

Want to be more creative? Check out this links:

- The reference to the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/planner-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0
- To test out the REST API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Hope it helps!

Comment: Many thanks, tried to connect with OData feed it got connected too but it is not fetching the proper data from task planner! I think I need to use Rest API to achieve this.

Comment: You need to fetch the task planner from the group (via Group ID) where it belongs. Other option is to build your own Azure Function acting as a service in between. I can't advise further since I don't know what's the exact requirement, but you can read Planner's Graph API to begin with.